# Split function, how to change?

Tags: php, split

```
if ($file) {
    while (!feof($file)) {
        $line = fgets($file);
        $line = trim($line);
        list ($date, $name, $email, $comment, $id) = split("\t", $line, 5);
        if (!strlen($date)) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I keep getting error for split code, but when I change it disrupts the functionality of my guestbook.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Split function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php

Comment: Change this line into list ($date, $name, $email, $comment, $id) = 
        explode("\t", $line, 5);

Comment: can you tell me which error you got it?